# Implementing shared logic for multiple KafkaListeners in spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My Spring Boot application contains several [`@KafkaListener`s](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-listener-annotation), and each listener performs the same steps before and after actually processing the payload: Validate the payload, check whether the event has been processed already, check whether it's a tombstone (null) message, decide whether processing should be retried in case of failure, emit metrics, etc.

These steps are currently implemented in a base class, but because the topics passed to `@KafkaListener` must be constant at runtime, the method annotated with @KafkaListener is defined in the subclass, and does nothing but pass its parameters to a method in the base class.

This works just fine, but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution. I assume my base class would have to create a listener container programmatically, but after a quick look at [`KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/b25e1441bdaa8d161415771649c2339af8da9e86/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java), it seems to be quite involved.

Does anyone have any recommendadtions?

Comment: I dont find ur solution not 'elegant' as such. Instead of creating several classes, do u want to create only 1 class?

Answer (score 3):

Having stumbled upon this question while looking to implement something similar, I first started with Artem Bilan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331279/9080066). However this did not work because annotations by default are not inherited in child classes unless they are themselves annotated with @Inherited. Despite this there may yet be a way to make an annotation approach work and I will update this answer if and when I get it to work. Thankfully though I have achieved the desired behavour using programtic registration of the Kafka listeners.

My code is something like the following:

Interface:

```
public interface GenericKafkaListener {

  String METHOD = "handleMessage";

  void handleMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record);
}
```

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericKafkaListener implements GenericKafkaListener {

  private final String kafkaTopic;

  public AbstractGenericKafkaListener(final String kafkaTopic) {
      this.kafakTopic = kafkaTopic;
  }

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
      //do common logic here
      specificLogic(record);
  }

  protected abstract specificLogic(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record);

  public String getKafkaTopic() {
      return kafkaTopic;
  }
}
```

We can then programtically register all beans of type AbstractGenericKafkaListener in a KafkaListenerConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaListenerConfigurataion implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private final List<AbstractGenericKafkaListener> listeners;

  @Autowired
  private final BeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Autowired
  private final MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory;

  @Autowired
  private final KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory;

  @Value("${your.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
  private String consumerGroup;

  @Value("${your.application.name}")
  private String service;

  @Override
  public void configureKafkaListeners(
    final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {

      final Method listenerMethod = lookUpMethod();

      listeners.forEach(listener -> {
        registerListenerEndpoint(listener, listenerMethod, registrar);
    });
  }

  private void registerListenerEndpoint(final AbstractGenericKafkaListener listener,
    final Method listenerMethod,
    final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {

      log.info("Registering {} endpoint on topic {}", listener.getClass(),
        listener.getKafkaTopic());

      final MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint =
        createListenerEndpoint(listener, listenerMethod);
      registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
  }

  private MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> createListenerEndpoint(
    final AbstractGenericKafkaListener listener, final Method listenerMethod) {

      final MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
      endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
      endpoint.setBean(listener);
      endpoint.setMethod(listenerMethod);
      endpoint.setId(service + "-" + listener.getKafkaTopic());
      endpoint.setGroup(consumerGroup);
      endpoint.setTopics(listener.getKafkaTopic());
      endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);

      return endpoint;
  }

  private Method lookUpMethod() {
      return Arrays.stream(GenericKafkaListener.class.getMethods())
        .filter(m -> m.getName().equals(GenericKafkaListener.METHOD))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() ->
            new IllegalStateException("Could not find method " + GenericKafkaListener.METHOD));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public abstract class BaseKafkaProcessingLogic {

     @KafkaHandler
     public void handle(Object payload) {

     }

}

@KafkaListener(topics = "topic1")
public class Topic1Handler extends BaseKafkaProcessingLogic {

}

@KafkaListener(topics = "topic2")
public class Topic2Handler extends BaseKafkaProcessingLogic {

}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same functionality and came up with solution close to [Artem Bilan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331279/3084507). Yes, `@KafkaHandler` annotation is not inherited by the child classes but defined in interface it is. Here is the solution:

```
interface AbstractKafkaListener<T> {

default Class<T> getCommandType() {
    TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<>(getClass()) {};

    return (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
}

@KafkaHandler
default void handle(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    T value = objectMapper.readValue(message, getCommandType());
    handle(value);
}

void handle(T message);
}
```

The class should implement the handle method only:

```
@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "my_topic")
public class KafkaListenerForMyCustomMessage implements AbstractKafkaListener<MyCustomMessage> {

@Override
public void handle(MyCustomMessage message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

The 2 implemented methods in the interface should be private/protected but because they are in interface this cannot be done. `default` methods are always public. Actually, all methods defined in interface are always public.

I use this solution to dynamically parse the message from kafka (received in **String**) to the custom class.

`getCommandType` method returns the class of the `T` generic param. `TypeToken` is from Google **Guava** package.